# Hyperledger Fabric: failed to execute transaction: timeout expired

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I have been working with Hyperledger Fabric and my chaincode involves a complicated calculation taking time. I wish to bump up the timeout times in the configuration so that the transaction can work. Here is the error and some logs just before it:

```
2018-10-11 08:00:01.370 UTC [msp] setupSigningIdentity -> DEBU 035 Signing identity expires at 2028-09-30 06:28:41 +0000 UTC
2018-10-11 08:00:01.370 UTC [msp] Validate -> DEBU 036 MSP Org1MSP validating identity
2018-10-11 08:00:01.372 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 037 parsed scheme: ""
2018-10-11 08:00:01.372 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 038 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2018-10-11 08:00:01.372 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 039 ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{peer0.org1.example.com:7051 0  <nil>}]
2018-10-11 08:00:01.373 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 03a ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2018-10-11 08:00:01.373 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03b pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc4204286d0, CONNECTING
2018-10-11 08:00:01.378 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03c pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc4204286d0, READY
2018-10-11 08:00:01.380 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 03d parsed scheme: ""
2018-10-11 08:00:01.380 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 03e scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2018-10-11 08:00:01.381 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 03f ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{peer0.org1.example.com:7051 0  <nil>}]
2018-10-11 08:00:01.381 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 040 ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2018-10-11 08:00:01.381 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 041 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42037da40, CONNECTING
2018-10-11 08:00:01.384 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 042 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42037da40, READY
2018-10-11 08:00:01.386 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 043 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-10-11 08:00:01.391 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 044 Sign: plaintext: 0AAC070A6808031A0C088186FCDD0510...63756C61746576616C75650A01350A00
2018-10-11 08:00:01.391 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 045 Sign: digest: 2BC62EB10423C00D8C9FAD8D8FE7B7C38157D6AA675064BC23BC0E191DD7F2AE

Error: endorsement failure during query. response: status:500 message:"failed to execute transaction f6e70bc375aa475eed82d2f31877286d52827aa22208ead7e51d2e01118a04f7: error sending: timeout expired while executing transaction"
```

Similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51559257/error-executing-chaincode-failed-to-execute-transaction-timeout-expired-while). As of now, I have tried increasing various timeout times in *core.yaml*, but nothing seems to work. I wanted to know which timeout is causing this issue specifically and how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There must be an error in your `chaincode` due to which your `chaincode` is getting crashed. A similar case has happened to me. Usually, your transaction will timeout if your chaincode crashed.

To debug, list all docker containers by:

`docker ps`

copy id of your `chaincode` container and execute this command:

`docker attach <container-id> -f`

execute the invoke/query command again. 
If there is a crash, logs will be printed where you executed `docker attach`